# What alternative is faster to create new rows based on an external vector in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

A typical use case where we want to duplicate rows to fit an external vector of length > 1 is when we want to introduce new dates, or allow for each date to show a different individual.

Imagine that we wanted to create measurements for each month in the iris dataset, one option would be to do it this way:

```r
group_and_tidyr_expand <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    group_by(pick(everything())) %>% 
    tidyr::expand(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-01-01"), to = as.Date("2023-01-01"), by = "1 month")) %>% 
    ungroup()
}
```

However, `dplyr` now has a function that allows to have more than one value (i.e., output row) per grouping, which is `reframe`. The equivalent to the code above would be:

```r
group_and_reframe <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    group_by(pick(everything())) %>% 
    reframe(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-01-01"), to = as.Date("2023-01-01"), by = "1 month"))
}
```

Which of these two alternatives is faster?

*Note: There is no need for `ungroup` to appear in reframe, as it already ungroups the output by default.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After benchmarking, it looks like `reframe` could be around three times faster than `tidyr::expand`.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    "reframe" = group_and_reframe(iris), 
    "tidyr_expand" = group_and_tidyr_expand(iris)
)

#> Unit: milliseconds
#>          expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#>       reframe  59.8355  63.90195  74.08853  70.2310  79.2985 219.7671   100
#>  tidyr_expand 207.6898 227.03515 261.62132 243.3526 269.4305 517.4461   100
```

Comment: Rerunning with `big_iris <- iris %>% uncount(1E4)` so we get 1.5M rows, the performance ratio is similar, with reframe taking a mean of 111ms vs tidyr_expand taking mean of 804ms.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: The below function should be much faster.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

library(bench)


big_iris <- iris %>% uncount(1E4)
distinct_expand <- function(df){
  out <- tidyr::expand_grid(dplyr::distinct(df), 
                     dplyr::tibble(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-01-01"), to = as.Date("2023-01-01"), by = "1 month")))
  dplyr::dplyr_reconstruct(out, df)
}
group_and_reframe <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    reframe(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-01-01"), to = as.Date("2023-01-01"), by = "1 month"),
            .by = everything())
}
mark(distinct_expand(big_iris), group_and_reframe(big_iris))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression                       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 distinct_expand(big_iris)      106ms    106ms      9.46    22.5MB    28.4 
#> 2 group_and_reframe(big_iris)    130ms    147ms      6.82    34.2MB     6.82
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>